# Symfony2/Doctrine - Get tags by blog

Tags: symfony, tags, doctrine

I'm trying to figure out a way to get tags by blog. I know you can just get all blogs and use a for loop to get the tags per blog but using this method I am unable to select on an individual tag, I end up having all tags instead of being able to select on just one tag.

Related to what I am trying to do here: [Symfony2 - How to you list one specific post tag instead of all of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207407/symfony2-how-to-you-list-one-specific-post-tag-instead-of-all-of-them)

The tags are setup as strings in the blog entity.

The query I'm theoretically trying to put together doesn't work---what is missing from it?

```
public function getTagsByBlog()
{
    $blogTags = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->select('b.id')
        ->where('b.id = :tag')
        ->setParameter('tag', 'b.tags');

    return $blogTags->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

entity

```
/**
 * Set tags
 *
 * @param string $tags
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setTags($tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select from tags table joined with blog (inside Tags repository), like this:

```
$blogTags = $this->createQueryBuilder('Tags')
        ->select('Tags.id')
        ->leftJoin('Tags.blog', 'Blog')
        ->where('Blog.id = :blogId')
        ->setParameter('blogId', $blogId);
```

This will create query with all tags ids related to Blog that has Id = $blogId.

Comment: So you're suggesting I create a tags entity? Right now tags are part of the blog entity as a string.

Comment: Oh, I thought it already have that relation. Yes you definytly should have ManyToMany ralation Blog-Tags.

Comment: Is there any way I can do it with the current way it's setup as a string property inside of the blog entity?

Comment: You can always convert string to array by using PHP explode function and then simply iterate through. EX: explode(',', $blog->getTags());

Comment: I'm looking to practice implementing tags as it's own entity per your suggestion. after setting up tags as an entity, what's the best way to setup the form in twig for tags? I have a blogs form, but how can I include this so I don't have to create a separate form for just tags?

Comment: Check this [Symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). There is complete example how can you do it.